# Using rails presenters - memoizable getting deprecated in 3.1 - use ||= instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, presenter, memoization

Issue: To avoid creating multiple objects or multiple queries when possible.

I am using Presenters with rails as a Best Practice.

I am following advice that says that it would be good to use "extend ActiveSupport.Memoizable" (and then memoize :method(s) to use them) over setting up items with `@the_record = record ||= @record` style because of a couple of issues - false or nil not getting stored so the query gets called again and also that memoizable uses the cache better (i.e. uses it!).

However I see that memoizable is getting deprecated in rails 3.1
Notes i github under carrierwave and with statement:
"DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Memoizable is deprecated and will be removed in future releases,simply use Ruby memoization pattern instead. (called from extend at /Users/kain/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/bundler/gems/carrierwave-c4459179b0f8/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:284".

Maybe it's been resolved though? Anyone know?

Any suggestions about the best practice to use going forward? Use the ||= syntax?  What about the above issues?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `||=` method is great for things that return values that evaluate as true, but it doesn't work very well for things that don't. `memoize` does work around this by trapping these conditions and returning accordingly. You might take an approach like this if you want to accommodate `nil`:

```
def some_method
  return @some_method if (instance_variable_defined?(:"@some_method"))

  @some_method = begin
    ...
  end
end
```

This just checks if the variable is defined, not if it is set, which is an important distinction in your case.

I'm not sure why you think it's being deprecated [Note from Michael, it's deprecated in 3.2, see note below]. The [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Memoizable/memoize) indicates it's still current in 3.1. Sometimes implementations are marked as "deprecated" when they're being moved from one module to another, but the facility remains available.

Comment: Well I looked around and maybe an older implementation was deprecated.  Anyway I will go with Memoizable now I know I can rely on it on 3.1  Thx tadman!

Comment: Wait I found the warning, it's on the excellent railsbest course about presenters and memoization.  They're well-known as the 'Rails for Zombies' course.  Anyway they gave the info on memoization, said how ActiveSupport options was best and yet their actual code challenge say "ActiveSupport::Memoizable (note: ActiveSupport::Memoizable is deprecated in Rails 3.1)" ! so still not sure about that and if it gets deprecated is that because the above issues would be resolved, etc..

Comment: Deprecated as of 3.2: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#activesupport_deprecations