# How to address "DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Memoizable is deprecated and will be removed in future releases"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warnings, ruby-on-rails-3.2, deprecated

After upgrading to Rails `3.2.0`, I started seeing the following deprecation warning in my *development log* and *test output*:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Memoizable is deprecated and will be removed in future releases,simply use Ruby memoization pattern instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/foo/bar/baz/bif/config/environment.rb:5)
```

Note the ending `config/environment.rb:5`, which is different [than](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9132197/664833) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7929946/664833) related (Memoizable) SO questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I traced this down to [this rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4678) (specifically [this comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4678#issuecomment-3660281)) and [this carrierwave issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/652).

The solution is to upgrade `carrierwave`:

**Gemfile diff**

```
-gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.5.8'
+gem 'carrierwave'
```

Remember to run `bundle update`.